# What is the best name convention for Flexbox classes?

Tags: flexbox

This question is not about the best names for ccs3 classes. It is very specific to the Flexbox that have basically two specific elements for the Father class and the children classes.

The website below explains it basically displaying two columns for each syntax you might use, the first column is for the Father and the Second for the children.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

My question is related the name of the Father and the Name for the Children (the flexbox items).

Im looking a pattern or examples to have the flexbox classes. For example for the Father or the Children I would use flex-container and flex-items as name class. But Im not sure if there is any convention or something better. Does anyone know if exist a name convention or something already created?
See example below:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-items {
  .item1 {
    flex-grow: 2;
 }
  .item2 {
   order: -1;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is regarding a specific ccs3 tecnology: flex-box.  And not a generic question about classes like the linked question.

Comment: Classes are classes. They don't change in nature or function because your in CSS, CSS2.1 or CSS3. I read your question. The duplicate applies in my opinion.